# How can I keep viewcontroller in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3, ios10

I am developing an app in Swift 3.0 with this hamburger menu like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfgx0.png).

So, in my menu `item1`, I have a `tableView` that loads information from my server and populates the table. when I select another viewController from the slide out menu and go back to my `item1`. It loads again the `tableView` and take some time to load (naturally).

My question is, How can i keep my `item1` in memory and not have to load the `tableView` again each time I want to open this `menuitem1VC`. The perfect way to load this `tableView` would be each time I open my app but I can't figure it out.

Comment: add code for push from slide menu .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this approach:

**1)** For the first time when you select your menu `item`, fetch `data` from `server` and store in either DB or somewhere else.

**2)** When you second time click the same `item`, first check if the `data` for that `item` is available locally or not.

**3)** It its available ,simply use it otherwise you will have to fetch again from `web service`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `UITabBarController` with hidden tab bar

```
tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

And on selecting the hamburger menu items, I'd programmatically change tab, i.e. when hamburger menu item at index 2 was selected:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
```

It covers all `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear` calls, so you wouldn't have to implement all that logic.